# How to change php include element with js?

Tags: javascript, php, php-include

I have two headers made in different php files.
 
One header is for index page only and other is for other pages. 
I included them with `php include_once` 
command 
and i need to set on index page when i scroll to remove first header and show other header. 
To do that i need to change include command, does anyone know how?

Comment: Just include both, and on scroll event hide one with JS

Comment: Instead of removing the first header it would be better to never include it in the first place. If you want more help you're going to have to share your code. Please [edit] your question and [add it there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Ok, do you think i should remove include and in js set when top page show first, when scroll show second?

Comment: Thanks guys i included both and then displayed header that i needed.